# Python 3.6.6 to Ubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, python, python3

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1.
I ran this commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

I upgraded my Python 3.6  from `3.6.2` to `3.6.5`
But Python `3.6.6` is available since 2018-06-27 How can I install it? Does it make sense that such an important package is not in the repository?

This important to me because `3.6.6` fixed a bug which I encounter in my code.

Running `apt-cache policy python3.6`  Gives:

```
python3.6:
  Installed: 3.6.5-5~16.04.york1
  Candidate: 3.6.5-5~16.04.york1
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.5-5~16.04.york1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I also get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

When running script using python3.6

Note: I have `python` which associate to `python2.7`,  `python3` which associate to `python3.5` and now I'm adding `python3.6`  - I don't want to overwrite other python installations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [jonathonf PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6) you are using has not included Python 3.6.6 yet. However, there is the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) which is the de-facto standard for installing non-default Python versions on Ubuntu.

Run the following commands to start using the deadsnakes PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

You should be able to install Python 3.6.6 on your Ubuntu 16.04 after that.

Optionally [remove the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/310/250300) “jonathonf” from your machine but this should not be necessary.

> Note: I have `python` which associate to `python2.7`, `python3` which associate to `python3.5` and now I'm adding `python3.6` - I don't want to overwrite other python installations.

The links `python` and `python3` are system default. A new version added using a PPA should not alter these links, so they will still behave as the system expects. The Python version installed from the PPA should be available as `python3.6`.

> But according to what I see they both go to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`.

These files are installed by the deadsnakes PPA:

```
$ dpkg -L python3.6
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3.6
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/README.txt
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/2to3-3.6
/usr/bin/pydoc3.6
/usr/bin/pygettext3.6
/usr/share
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/python3.6
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python3.6
/usr/share/doc/python3.6/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3.6/README.rst.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3.6/ACKS.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3.6/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/python3.6/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python3.6/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/python3.6.desktop
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/2to3-3.6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pydoc3.6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pysetup3.6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pdb3.6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pygettext3.6.1.gz
/usr/share/pixmaps
/usr/share/pixmaps/python3.6.xpm
/usr/bin/pdb3.6
/usr/share/doc/python3.6/changelog.gz
```

The only thing going to the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` directory is the `README.txt` file. It won’t overwrite current contents.

Comment: can I have both 3.5 and 3.6 without mutual effect on each other?

Comment: But according to what I see they both go to /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/  If I upgrade one package using python3.6 wouldn't it effect the python 3.5 ? The package is saved on the same place.

Comment: @Programmer120 I tried to install Python3.6 from deadsnakes on one of my machines and it only added `README.txt` to the mentioned folder. It seems to be safe.